# A GET API (google sheets API) returns an excel sheet in windows 1252 encoding format. How can I download the sheet as excel using nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, google-sheets, google-drive-api

This is the response API gives

[image]

This is the code snippet.

```
axios.get(api , { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}` , "Content-Type":"application/json" , "Accept" : "*/*", "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br"} })
  .then(res => {
  try {     
  let fileString = iconv.decode(res.data, 'win1252');
  fs.writeFile('NodeReport.xlsx' , fileString , (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

  }
  catch (err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  }
```

);

So if I hit the API in browser it downloads the excel file , and If I save response from Postman as file it also downloads excel file . But I want to hit the API from my nodeJS code and then save the file as Excel file . I have tried to use fs.writeFile but it doesn't open the saved file , it says the format is wrong or content is corrupted. Can anyone tell how can I save this file from API response ?

Comment: About `But I want to hit the API from my nodeJS code and then save the file as Excel file . I have tried to use fs.writeFile but it doesn't open the saved file , it says the format is wrong or content is corrupted.`, can you provide your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike Edited question and added code snippet

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide your sample endpoint? And, can I ask you about the reason you are required to use `windows 1252 encoding format`?

Comment: @Tanaike This is the endpoint https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bWZwbUohxPJDyu_vMyPrYxEFb8ruAr_hHb7IQ7BGYLU/export?format=xlsx&id=1bWZwbUohxPJDyu_vMyPrYxEFb8ruAr_hHb7IQ7BGYLU

And I have no specific Window 1252 requirement , I just want to save whatever is coming in response as excel file, but I guess it is window 1252 format , so using it. But my goal is just to download that weird string in response to a excel file

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Still getting the file format error on opening excel file that is saved.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your exported data from `Still getting the file format error on opening excel file that is saved.`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, when I tested my script using your provided Spreadsheet, I can correctly open the XLSX file without the error. So, I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. So, when I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of the reason and solution. In the current stage, my proposed script is not useful for your situation. So, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, as a modification, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
axios
  .get(api, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
  })
  .then((res) => {
    try {
      fs.writeFile("NodeReport.xlsx", res.data, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

- In this modification, the data is retrieved as the array buffer and saved the data as an XLSX file.
- If the exported file is broken, please modify `fs.writeFile("NodeReport.xlsx", res.data, (error) => {` to `fs.writeFile("NodeReport.xlsx", new Buffer.from(res.data), (error) => {` and test it again.

#### Reference:

- [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: Using these both things you provided I still get same error on opening excel " Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that file is not corrupted and that file format matches the file extension"

Comment: @Shubham Seth Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I tested my script, a Google Spreadsheet are exported as an XLSX file. And, I can open it. I have to apologise that when I tested my proposed script, the script works fine. This is due to my poor skill. So from `Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that file is not corrupted and that file format matches the file extension`, it is required to know the exported file. So, can you see the exported file using a text editor? And, can you provide the data of the file?

Comment: I have pasted the exported value in this link https://justpaste.it/77muw , You can check

Comment: @Shubham Seth Thank you for replying. It seems that from your provided data, the data is XLSX data. But, when I tested my script again, the valid XLSX file is created. So, for example, when your exported data is uploaded to your Google Drive, the file can be opened on Google Drive?

Comment: I have made the sheet public , can you please check it yourself by downloading and share your script with me if it opens https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bWZwbUohxPJDyu_vMyPrYxEFb8ruAr_hHb7IQ7BGYLU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Shubham Seth By the way, when you modify `fs.writeFile("NodeReport.xlsx", res.data, (error) => {` to `fs.writeFile("NodeReport.xlsx", new Buffer.from(res.data), (error) => {` or `fs.writeFile("NodeReport.xlsx", { encoding: 'binary' }, res.data, (error) => {`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Shubham Seth Thank you for providing the sample Spreadsheet. When I used my proposed script using your provided sample Spreadsheet, I can open the exported XLSX file. So, it seems that this issue doesn't depend on the Spreadsheet data. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: When I changed to new Buffer.from(res.data) it downloaded and on opening gave error , BUT when I used encoding: binary it gives this error " TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Object
    at Object.writeFile (node:fs:2123:5)
    at C:\Users\prog\Documents\GoogleSheets\index.js:231:20
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE' "

Comment: can you share the entire code from top to bottom that you used to download the spreadsheet please . I will check it with my own then . Thanks for help

Comment: @Shubham Seth Thank you for replying. I tested my script by adding `const axios = require("axios").default;` and `const fs = require("fs");` and `const api = "###` and `const token = "###"` to my proposed script.

Comment: @Shubham Seth By the way, you are using the latest version of axios and your access token can be used for downloading the file. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes I am using latest version and access token is correct , I can download it. But when i save to local using fs ,it doesn't open.

Comment: @Shubham Seth From your comment, when you used my proposed answer, I could confirm that your issue was resolved. So, I reopened my answer.